# 動的に生成されるテーブル中のINPUT要素を、配列化してPHP・JS側双方で捉えたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

皆様、いつも大変御世話になっております。
PHP側で要素を配列として認識できる、との記事をおみかけし、
自分のHTMLに当てはめようとして頭を悩ましています。

テーブル行はJSで動的に形成されます。
こちらの行に含まれるINPUT要素に、本日までは"[]"を付けていませんでしたが
見ようみまねで"[]"を付けてみました．．．

PHP側での取得にいざ挑戦しようとコーディングを始めたところ．．．

それ以前にJQueryで、当該INPUT項目の認識ができなくなってしまいました。
例えばコレ：

```
$("input[name=cd]").keydown(function(event) {
```

====質問====
以下がコーディングになりますが、テーブル行に収められたINUPUT要素（名前属性=cdとamount）
を配列として処理するため、
JS側とPHPでは　どういった記述を施せばよろしいのでしょうか？
JSは

```
$("input[name=cd]").keydown(function(event) {
```

の正しい記載方法を教えて頂ければ幸いです。
PHPは

```
if (isset($_POST["cd"]) && is_array($_POST["cd"])) {
    $arr_item = $_POST["food"];
}
```

で捉えられるのでしょうか？

```
====HTML====
<!--### 右端の＋ボタン・－ボタンで自由に行を増減できる ###-->
<table>
    <tr class="appLineDummy">
        <td><input type="text" name="cd[]" style="width:45px; ime-mode: inactive;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" style="width:45px;"></td>
        <td><button class="rowins" type="button">+</button></td>
        <td><button class="rowdel" type="button">-</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>



====JQuery====
var $dummyRow = $("tr.appLineDummy");

//### 初回の画面呼び出し時 10行の明細を生成 ###//
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        addRowBelow($dummyRow);
    }
});

// テーブル行追加
$(document).on("click", ".rowins", function(e) {
    var $row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        addRowBelow($row);
});
// テーブル行削除
$(document).on("click", ".rowdel", function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    $(row).remove();
    downtotalCalc();
});



//品名ＣＤのテキストボックスにフォーカスが入って、希望出荷日が指定されていなかったら．．．
//エラー回避の検知は希望出荷日の入力有無で行っています。
$("input[name=cd]").keydown(function(event) {
    if ($("#calendar").val() == "") {
        errhandler($(this), true, "err#011");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryでは以下でname属性が配列でもイベント検知できます。

```
$('input[name="cd[]"]').keydown(function(event) {
```

PHP側はご質問の方法で配列として捉えることができます。`$_POST["cd"]`これ自体がkeyが0で始まるの配列になって渡ってきますので、

```
//※イメージです
$_POST["cd"] = array(　
     0 => ”hoge”,
     1 => ”hogehoge”,
)
```

foreachやarray_関数を利用して操作を行ってください。
http://php.net/manual/ja/language.types.array.php

Comment: keitaro_so様　早速のご支援をありがとうございました。ほっとしました。